# Can we access static method using objects?

Tags: oop, static-methods

It is said that static function can be accessed using class name instead of class object. But I can access static function using both i.e. class name and object of same class.

Which way is correct?

Comment: If you have a choice, use the class name prefix. This will make it clear you are calling a class method. It is good practice, like always using the "this" prefix in C-family languages when referencing instance members so you can easily tell them apart from local variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation details of a specific language. Class is enough to access the static method thus object isn't needed; class can be specified directly or implicitly deduced from an object. The latter is actually a syntactic sugar that can be optionally provided by the language.

Comment: Thanks. Language is PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Theorically you can use both the instance identifier and type identifier to call a static method.

Things may change when you want to take the address of a static method. Some languages will only return a simple pointer when using `&Type.staticMethod` and a fat pointer when using `&instance.staticMethod`.